# How do I capture difference in date/time as seconds:milleseconds with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a stopwatch function within Google Sheets, and I'm having some trouble in getting `var diff` to show the difference in seconds:milleseconds between `var currentTime` and `var previousTiming`. For some reason, I'm only retrieving a 'NaN' value.

The thought is that there will be an image on the "Timer" sheet, which users will click to start timings, along with a "lap" function which moves the active cell down 1 row from the current to capture the next time. Right now, I have it placing the current time it captures in the activeCell(), but would like to change it to the `var diff` value, if I can get it to have the right format.

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
function timer() {
    // Getting Active Sheet Details
    var spreadsheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
    var spreadsheetTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var currentTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss:ms");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetName = dataSheet.getName().toString();

    // If the active sheet name contains "tim", continue
    if (sheetName.indexOf("Tim") > -1) {
        var totalBreakpoints = dataSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(function(row) {
            return row[0];
        });
        var headers = dataSheet.getRange("C1:1").getValues().filter(function(row) {
            return row[0];
        });

        // Get the total number of rows/columns to look at
        var numberRows = totalBreakpoints.length;
        var numberColumns = ss.getLastColumn();

        // Get the range that can accept times
        var valuesRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 3, numberRows, numberColumns);

        // Getting Active Cell Details
        var activeCell = dataSheet.getActiveCell();
        var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
        var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
        var cellAbove = activeCell.offset(-1, 0).getValue();
        var previousTiming
        if (activeRow <= 2 || cellAbove == '') {
            previousTiming = currentTime;
        } else {
            previousTiming = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(cellAbove), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss:ms");
        };

        // Check to see if within range            
        if (activeCell.getRow() >= valuesRange.getRow() && activeCell.getRow() <= valuesRange.getLastRow() &&
            activeCell.getColumn() >= valuesRange.getColumn() && activeCell.getColumn() <= valuesRange.getLastColumn()) {
            activeCell.setValue(currentTime);
            dataSheet.getRange(activeRow + 1, activeColumn).activate();
            var diff = Math.abs(currentTime - previousTiming);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create `var ss` after already calling `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` multiple times? Make `ss` first then do `ss.getName() ` and `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`...

Comment: Ahh, good catch. That makes more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `NaN` as the value for diff is because [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format) returns a String - you are subtracting two strings, which is most certainly not a number.

The solution is to only apply the formatting when printing to the cell, and let `currentTime` and `previousTime` remain native `Date` objects, e.g.

```
activeCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(....));
```

Probably a better solution is to apply a datetime number format to the cells which hold the timing information, and write the actual number (not a formatted string) to the cells in question. This way you can be sure that when you read the value of the previous row's cell, that it is read as a number and can be used as such.

e.g.

```
// Time in col A, differential in col B
function lapImageClicked() {
  var now = new Date();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 2);
  // Write date into A, and milliseconds differential in B
  last.offset(1, 0).setValues([ [now, now - last.getValues()[0][0]] ]);
}
```

Comment: Hey tehowch. Thanks for the reply (as always). I attempted the function you have, and it successfully inserted rows at the very bottom of the page, with the date in A:A, and MS in B:B. What I'm trying in the activeCell() is if it is in row 2 or if the cell above is blank, then I want to put the timestamp. Then, in each cell below, I want to calculate the seconds:milleseconds difference between the cell above and activeCell().

Comment: Yes, it makes the assumption that your timer sheet is just used for timing. For the exact function supplied to be adding to the very bottom of your sheet, you must have data entered in lower cells. (e.g. your current sheet times in cells A1:B10, but have comments, charts, etc in C100). My function is not meant to solve your exact problem as stated, but to offer an example from which you can learn ways to improve your approach.

Comment: tehowch, perfect. I'll play with it, to see what I can do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
function calcTimeDifference(Start,End)
{
  if(Start && End)
  {
    var second=1000;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    var seconds=Math.floor(d/second);
    var milliseconds=Math.floor(d%seconds);
    return 'ss:ms\n' + seconds + ':' + milliseconds;  
  }
  else
  {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Note: 
valueOf() just returns the numerical value in milliseconds.  Play around with this a bit.

```
function  ttestt(){
  var dt1=new Date();
  var dt2=dt1.valueOf()-100000;
  Logger.log('dt1=%s dt1-dt2=%s',dt1.valueOf(),dt1.valueOf()-dt2.valueOf());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Cooper. I've tried doing the .valueOf() for both currentTime and previousTiming, but `var diffinms` gets the same NaN result. Am I interpreting that incorrectly?